# vtk runnable jar file

Tags: executable-jar, vtk

I have created an application using VTK java wrapper and java swing in Eclipse IDE. Now, I want to make a runnable jar file of the application so that I can run it on the different computer on which VTK is not installed.
I have created a jar file and have included vtk.jar while creating it. Also I have created a folder in which I am placing the jar file and debug folder (from VTK-bin/bin) which includes all the required dlls. When I am trying to run this jar file on the other computer, it gives unsatisfiedlinkerror.
What is the correct procedure to create a runnable jar file for VTK application?

Answer (score 0):

The issue regarding executable jar file of VTK application is resolved. I compiled VTK in release mode instead of debug mode. For distribution purpose, debug is not used because of its additional dependencies. Also, I included jre/bin in path environmetal variable of target machine, which I had forgotten to do earlier.
Now, I am able to run jar file on the machine in which VTK is not installed.